# What happens to html5 audio tag in iphone when it goes to lockscreen?

Tags: javascript, input, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I'm trying "Sequential Play aka playlist" by html audio tag. File sources are from user's mobile itself. The user will choose multiple files from the input and it will start playing on loading automatically if Android, and user has to click play at first instance if iphone.

Therefore, I tried ***URL.createObjectURL***, ***web audio api***, ***file reader***.
Everything works perfectly fine in Android. When the first audio file finishes playing, with onended listener, it plays next file. prev/next button works ok too. But on iphone (ios 13), it doesn't work once screen goes lock. It only allows first file to be ended.

At first, I thought problem was

> safari doesn't allow audio.play() without user interaction.

To narrow down the reason of error, I linked files source from Google Drive or Dropbox. In this case, next file plays graciously, whether screen went to lock or not on iphone too.

So problem must be using local files in iphone. It does play first one when play button is clicked. Then first file will finish play and when it goes to next loading, it throws error(code:4 from audio element's error event) if files are from local and the screen was off for a while. Onended event as well as prev/next button click.

I couldn't check with web audio api because same code doesn't work on iphone which works in Android. It doesn't play at all even the first file. Play button doesn't work at all.

*Source codes*

**Html**

```
<label class="custom-file-upload">
  <input type="file" accept='audio/*' multiple> Load </label>
<audio type="audio/mp4" controls></audio>
```

**Javascript**

```
const input = document.querySelector("input[type=file]");
const audio = document.querySelector("audio"); 
const output = document.getElementById("output"); 
const speedzone = document.querySelector('#speedzone');
const choice = document.getElementById('cnext');
const choice1 = document.getElementById('cprev');

let listLength, j, files;

const playList = files => {
  if (j-- >=0) {
    let listFile ='';
    for (let i = listLength-1 ; i>=0 ;i--) {
      listFile += (i==j)?`<div class=list><b>${files[i].name} ${(+files[i].size/1024/1024).toFixed(2)} MB</div>`
        : `<div>${files[i].name}</div>`;
     }

    output.innerHTML = listFile;
    let listDiv = document.querySelector('.list');
    output.scrollTop = listDiv.offsetTop;

    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[j]);
    audio.load();
  }
}
  input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    files = [...e.target.files].sort((a, b) => { return b.name.localeCompare(a.name); });
    j = listLength = files.length;
    playList(files);
  });

audio.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {audio.play();});
  audio.addEventListener("ended", () => {choice.click();});
  audio.addEventListener("error", (e) => {
    const err = e.target.error;
    let txt = speedzone.innerHTML;
    txt += `<div><font color=red>${err.code}: ${err.message}</font></div>`;
    speedzone.innerHTML = txt;
   });

  choice.addEventListener('click', () => {if (j>0) playList(files);});
  choice1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //previous
    if (j<listLength-1) {
      j+=2;
      choice.click();
    }
  });
```

Currently, I doubt that when the screen locks, unlike Android, iphone's files expire their link. Because URL.createObjectURL are called only when they are needed so there is no question of url expired.
Weirdly, files array still have their information as it was first allocated. So where I keep the list, output, it gives list and currently selected file's size correctly. I can still click prev/next and they do their job except audio. I can't seem to know where the error comes from.

That's when I tried web audio api.

```
const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
```

Then in function playList,

```
const track = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);

track.connect(audioContext.destination);
if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
  audioContext.resume();
}
```

Works perfectly as same as other two methods in Android. But it wouldn't play at all on iphone.

As a last resort, I want to try this web audio api. But as it wouldn't play, I can't be sure if the result would be same as other two. Also as I doubt, if the problem is on the getting files itself.

How to make this web audio api work on iphone? And is there any restriction of using input[type=file] on iphone?

** Edit **
I found even the audio element throws error, filereader's url and  URL.createObjectURL gets url ok. It seems a bit of audio tag's problem in the end. Still no solution...

Comment: You need to hook into the AUDIO ended event and change the src to the new audio file

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=173332

Comment: @Chris Love
Thanks for the attention. Sounds like it may work. However, I gave up on iPhone support for this. So I can't be sure. Anyway thanks again.